# Duda sobre Polimorfismo y arreglos en C++

Tags: c++, poo, array, polimorfismo

Tengo una duda acerca de el uso de arreglos con polimorfismo, el tema es así:
Tengo una clase Articulo de la que heredan dos clases Libro y Cd.

```
class Articulo {

   protected:

     string nom;
   public:

     Articulo();
     virtual void mostrar() = 0;
}

class Libro : public Articulo{

   private:

     string autor;

   public:

     Libro();
     void mostrar();
     void verAutor();

}

class Cd : public Articulo{

   private:

     string compositor;

   public:

      Libro();
      void mostrar();
      void verCompositor();
}
```

Luego tengo una clase Negocio que gestiona un vector de articulos cargado con instancias de libro y cd.

```
class Negocio {

   private

     std::vector<Articulo*> vArticulos;

   public:

     Negocio();

     std::vector<Libro*> buscarPorAutor();
     std::vector<Cd*> buscarPorComp();

}
```

Dentro de Negocio tengo dos métodos uno para buscar artículos por autor *(que devuelve libros)* y otro por compositor *(devuelve cds)* . Tanto en libro como en `cd` tengo métodos para ver el autor y el compositor , ¿Cómo puedo saber De que instancia es cada elemento del vector de artículos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas usar `dynamic_cast`. Te pongo un ejemplo para extraer los libros:

```
std::vector<Libro*> seleccionarLibros()
{
  std::vector<Libro*> libros;
  for( size_t i=0; i<vArticulos.size(); i++ )
  {
    if( Libro* libro = dynamic_cast<Libro*>(vArticulos[i]) )
    {
      // Una vez obtenido el puntero puedes utilizarlo con normalidad
      libro->verAutor(); 
      libros.push_back(libro);
  }
  return libros;
}
```

`dynamic_cast` funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Solo se puede usar con clases que tengan algún tipo de herencia. En caso contrario da error en tiempo de compilación.
- Se ha de compilar con [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) habilitado (suele ser una opción por defecto). En caso contrario da error  en tiempo de compilación.
- No se puede usar para convertir de un tipo heredado a otro base (error de compilación). Esta conversión es automática y no requiere operaciones adicionales.
- Si el puntero base puede ser convertido al tipo heredado entonces lo convierte, en caso contrario devuelve un puntero nulo.